# Fluid width with text-overflow ellipsis

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, stylesheet

I'm trying to make inner div with fluid width and `...` when overflow (using `ellipsis`).

**Requirements**:

1. `.container` has fixed known width `200px`
2. `.badge` could be any width but max is `30px`. This is because this div contains a number (from 0 to 999). This must stay `right` (float right).
3. `.content` and `.badge` must be in same line
4. `.content` will have ellipsis and nowrap. Must stay `left`
5. Key important: **`.content`'s width = `.container`'s width - `.badge`'s width**

I could not get `#5` above to happen. Any pointer?

My code below either made the `.badge` to wrap in second line or the `.content` just doesn't expand its width.

**HTML**:

```
<div class=container>
    <div class=content>
        Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus
    </div>
    <div class=badge>
        5
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.container {
    width: 200px;
    background: gray;
}

.content {
    display: inline-block;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 170px;
    background: green;
}

.badge {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 30px;
    background: yellow;
    float: right;
}
```

**Link:** http://jsfiddle.net/qhoc/4w6wR/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div class=container>
    <div class=badge>
        5
    </div>
    <div class=content>
        Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus
    </div>    
</div>

.container {
    width: 200px;
    background: gray;
}

.content {    
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;    
    background: green;
}

.badge {
    float:right;
    max-width: 30px;
    background: yellow;    
}
```

Comment: awesome... saved me so much headache