# Set the min and max -width of a table in number of characters

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table, column-width

I need to set the max-width of a table column to be 20 characters.
I'm using the following CSS which works fine.

```
th{
    width: 13ch;
}
```

However it does not not work with max-width. If a table cell value is only 10 characters in width I only want it to be 10ch.

Is this possible in CSS to set the min and max width of a table cell

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26973570/setting-a-max-character-length-in-css it is possible for a max width just fine.

Comment: This doesn't work for a table cell unfortunately

Comment: Seems to work here - https://jsfiddle.net/m0bn5aet/1/