# Ruby Truncate method equivalent in CSS

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there an equivalent of the Ruby [`truncate`](https://apidock.com/rails/String/truncate) method in CSS for a specific number of characters?

I have been reading up on combining different CSS methods such as text-overflow:

[Setting a max character length in css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26973570/setting-a-max-character-length-in-css)

but there doesn't seem to be a straight forward solution to replicate the `truncate` functionality after a specific number of characters such as:

```
<%= truncate(this.thing, length: 15, separator: '...') %>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42880446/2968762

Comment: @Abhi in that answer the text is truncated after 93 characters. It could work only if the text was monospaced (https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bRELeb)

Comment: Yes and the text is only on one line. Also, if the text is on more than one line it will not work.

Comment: @fcalderan The codepen in the comments looked promising, so I suggested

Comment: @abhi I've inserted it after your first comment

Answer (score 0):

I did find this css [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp):

```
white-space: nowrap; 
width: 15em; 
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis; 
border: 1px solid #000000;
```

With modern browsers it seems to do what you expect.

Comment: I take it this will work only for monospace font ? Because em will not take into account varying character widths.

Comment: Does it really matter if you see one char more or less? In many cases you don`t have enough space and you want to truncate the string. With rails version you have to take less chars just to be sure it will fit into the reserved space. With css it will always truncated when it does not fit into the reserved space.

Comment: It may not matter in this particular context and I am not downvoting the answer because it may satisfy OP's requirement. 

I am just pointing out that this may not "exactly" do what is claimed.