# How can i ensure the paragraph have fixed number of characters with CSS?

Tags: html, css

For example, i want **exact** 9 characters (with no extra chars/whitespaces) in the text paragraph below with CSS. (i set width to 9rem, fontsize to 1rem below)

Tried letter-spacing, inline-block, monospace font etc without luck.

```css
.texts {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 9rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-family: monospace;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid palevioletred;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: 0;
}
```

```html
<p class='texts'>ninechars with extra chars</p>
```

Comment: `width:9ch` ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/26975271/244811

Comment: If you use `display: inline-block` the width will fit the content. Is that what's desired?

Comment: @arbuthnott thanks for your advice, sorry for my poor description of problem. Seems there's an answer does what i want, just need to confirm it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can achieve what you're after using the code below

```css
p.texts { overflow: hidden; max-width: 9ch; }
```

```html
<p class='texts'>ninechars</p>
```

And you can check the compatibility here - https://caniuse.com/#search=ch

Answer (score 1):

```
   <style> 
   #para1 {
        white-space: nowrap; 
        max-width: 9ch;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis; 
        border: 1px solid #000000;
    }
    </style>

    <p id="para1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing </p>
```