# Remove max character width

Tags: html, css, wordpress

So I'm working on this website using a wordpress template from Massive Dynamic. One of my elements (screenshot attached) has a max character length. I've tried removing it for hours. The max character length is 20 characters.
Any css I need to remove or is it some new CSS I need to add?

Help me out
Thanks

Site: Numbersnumbers.dk

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting a max character length in css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26973570/setting-a-max-character-length-in-css)

Comment: Seems like it is not truncated from the CSS styles. I's probably an automatic PHP process of `Massive Dynamic`.

Comment: What happens when the text reaches the max-width threshold?

Comment: When it reaches max, it stops typing. Can I edit the PHP process of Massive Dynamic?

Comment: You mean, the input field in the backend has the length limit? Otherwise, what do you mean by "it stops typing"?

Comment: Post your code if you want proper help.

Answer (score -1):

Just add

```
word-wrap: break-word !important;
```

to the element and it should work.
I've tried on your website with Chrome DevTools and it worked :)

Comment: In what way is this related to the question? He needs to remove the length limit, not break words onto a new line.

Comment: Now the section from the website has been removed, so i cannot try again.
It is releated, because maybe it wasn't a 20 chars limit, but simply the overflowed content was hidden, so breaking words would display them all; but i have to retry to see if i made a mistake and my solution is not correct. :)