# How to limit the character count in CSS

Tags: html, jquery, css

I am creating a multilingual website where the plugin in I am using only provides the option to show the language name entirely. I want to limit the character count to only 3 characters. Example: If the language is **English** I only want to display it as **ENG**, When it's **Vietnamese** it will be **VIE**.

I already tried

```css
span {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span>English</span>
</p>
<p>
  <span>Vietnamese</span>
</p>
```

I don't want the `...` appear with the first three letters and setting a `width` or `max-width` is not effective to show only 3 characters in some languages as you see in the above snippet. Is there are any alternative approaches there? Let me know, please.

Comment: Related. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26973570/setting-a-max-character-length-in-css/26975271#26975271

Answer (score 0):

that ? with `font-family:monospace;`

```css
span {
  font-size      : 30px;
  display        : inline-block;
  width          : 3ch;
  font-family    : monospace;
  overflow       : hidden;
  text-transform : uppercase;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span>English</span>
</p>
<p>
  <span>Vietnamese</span>
</p>
```

Comment: Wow. This one is cool, but another problem raises here. I am using the Oswald font in the website theme. Monospace replaces it

Comment: with monospace font you have to use `width:3ch`

Comment: @TemaniAfif thank you, I forgot this unit

Comment: @Ramesh You can't have your cake and eat it too.