# Fluid text on several line with text-overflow ellipsis

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build a fluid content width with text ellipsis.. I found this question: 
[Fluid width with text-overflow ellipsis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20552957/fluid-width-with-text-overflow-ellipsis)

My requirements are almost the same, but :

1. `.container` has fixed known width 320px
2. `.extra-text` (.badge inside the previous question) could be any width but should not be more then 60px
3. `.content` and `.extra-text` must be wrap as a paragraph, and cannot be more then 2 lines with a max-height of 44px; .extra-text will be at the end of second line if `.content` has a lot of text
4. `.content` could be one word or long text and will have ellipsis to be contained inside `.container` if it is a long text

*Browser supports : IE9*

```css
.container {    
    width: 320px;
    max-height: 44px;    
    position: relative; 
    background: #e2e2e2;
    text-align: center;
}

/** Demo */
.container + .container {
    margin-top: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <span class="content">TITLE</span>
    <span class="extra-content">extra-text</span>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <span class="content">ANOTHER LONGER LONG LONG LONG LONG LONG LONG LONG LONG TITLE</span>
    <span class="extra-content">extra-text</span>
</div>
```

So in second block the latest words "LONG TITLE" should be ellipsis and extra-text should be there..

***EDIT*** for precision :

Here a "spec" of what I need :

```
+-------------------+
|lorem ipsum example|
|lorem ipsum example|
|lorem ... extra-txt|/* Content is long, "..." is need to display extra-txt */
+-------------------+

+-------------------+
|lorem extra-txt    |/* Here content is short so I don't need ellipsis. */
+-------------------+
```

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33058004/3597276

Comment: @Michael_B not exactly, because it doesn't fix the problem I have with extra-content

Comment: Based on your item (3), it appears your asking for ellipsis on multiline text. Correct?

Comment: Yes I need to appliy ellipsis on probably multiline text, but I need an extra-text to be displayed at the end of the lines, as inline element, just after the ellipsis and inside the same parent container

Comment: Well, with standard CSS ellipsis, using the `text-overflow` property, `white-space: nowrap` is a requirement. Therefore, ellipsis can only work on a single line of text. That's the reason I referred you to the other post. It has workaround options for ellipsis on multiline text.

Comment: Yes the workaround options work for ellipsis on multiline text, but I still cannot figure  how to make the text stop before the end of the last line as the `extra-text` can finish it

Comment: @Michael_B see my edit for more precision